# How to clone struct addrinfo properly

Tags: tcp, udp

I need to clone an existing struct addrinfo pointer. I have written below code to clone it. Thought it works fine from functuonality point of view, but I get memory leak when I free cloned strutc addrinfo pointer.

```
struct addrinfo * transport_clone_addrinfo(struct addrinfo *src)
{
    struct addrinfo *dst;

    if(src == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    dst = calloc(1, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    dst->ai_next = NULL;

    dst->ai_flags = 0; 
    dst->ai_family = src->ai_family;
    dst->ai_socktype = src->ai_socktype;
    dst->ai_protocol = src->ai_protocol;
    dst->ai_canonname = NULL;
    dst->ai_addrlen = src->ai_addrlen;
    dst->ai_addr = malloc(src->ai_addrlen);
    memcpy(dst->ai_addr, src->ai_addr, src->ai_addrlen);

    return dst;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *ip = "192.168.1.10";
    unsigned short port = 5555;
    int index;
    int ret_val = -1;
    char service[8];
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *rp = NULL;
    struct addrinfo *rp2;

    index = sprintf(service, "%u", port);
    service[index] = 0;

    if(true)
    {
        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        ret_val = getaddrinfo(ip, NULL, &hints, &rp);
    }
    else
    {
        ret_val = getaddrinfo(ip, service, NULL, &rp);
    }

    if(ret_val != 0)
    {
        printf("\ngetaddrinfo failed\n");
    }

    rp2 = transport_clone_addrinfo(rp);

    freeaddrinfo(rp);
    freeaddrinfo(rp2);

    return 0;
}
```

With this, functionality wise it works fine. But valgrind reports memory leak for below line of code.

```
dst->ai_addr = malloc(src->ai_addrlen);
```

Then I checked freeaddrinfo code, I see ai_addr member of struct addrinfo is not freed explicitly.

Probably I am missing something while cloning. Can somebody help me to understand how to clone struct addrinfo right way.

Is there any C api to clone struct addrinfo?

Comment: Did you get any way out. I have some problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is an trick for getaddrinfo implement, It would malloc whole memory (sizeof (struct addrinfo) + ai_addrlen) for rp, so freeaddrinfo would just free the rp and rp.ai_canonname.

Comment: While this works for GNU/Linux with glibc, the unix standard does not actually define how addrinfo structures are allocated or freed other than through getaddrinfo and freeaddrinfo, so while duplicating the glibc trick works with glibc, it might trigger undefined behaviour (e.g. crashes, memory corruption) with other implementations. That means there is no standards-condoned way to copy addrinfo structures.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try and clone struct addrinfo. If you really want to copy, create a different struct name is something like my_addrinfo. You can then copy the fields like you did. Then provide a function to free this struct.